# How do I send information from my Overridden ActionListener method to the main method in Java?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, overriding

Basically, I'm a newbie creating a program that gives questions, randomizes the index of the right answer and then displays the questions in a JFrame.
I can easily perform any tasks that I add to this ActionListener method:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("whatever");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "correct!", 
                "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "wrong!", 
                "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

The program gets the "1" from setActionCommand given in the main method, yet I want the Listener to return to the main method something that when the correct radiobutton is clicked, then the next question will be displayed as well.
The main method is made like:

```
while (therearestillquestionsleft) { /* do everything */ }
```

so I need the program to wait in the loop until the right answer is clicked.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: You wouldn't. You would initiate that action in the `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Your design is way off. Believe me, you *don't* want this to communicate with or "return to" the main method, since main should be written to just set up and start your program and do nothing more. It sounds like you need to do some serious re-design of your program.

Comment: I have a lot of JOptionPane's in the beginning getting the information from the user in the main method. That should stay there, right?

Comment: Then I proceed to making the window, the buttons, assigning the right index to the right button and making the program understand and tell to the ActionListener when the correct one is selected. Should this be in a different class? How could I make this repeatable so that this would start again when the right answer is picked? This should probably be a different class.

Comment: Instead of flashing a bunch of JOptionPane dialogs at the user, why not get all of the information that you need in one GUI? But regardless, I stand by my advice that the main method should be used just to set up your program and start it, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, waiting in a loop is not the way to handle waiting for GUI user input in Java.

You could instead redesign your program to look something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // [...]
    nextQuestion();
}

public static void nextQuestion() {
    if (questionsLeft) {
        // "do everything", i.e. show next question
    }
}
```

Then, you can simply call `nextQuestion()` from within your `ActionListener`.